# Modify LDAP attribute fails from Java, but succeeds with ldapmodify command

Tags: java, ssl, ldap, openldap, tls1.2

I manage to perform a STARTTLS ldapmodify ( -ZZ) of an attribute, but fail to perform the same modification using javax.naming.ldap coding

The server is OpenLDAP. It has SSigned SSL Certificate for modification, and unsecured reading is allowed. Classical combination.

I run the following command from the same server on which I will try to execute the Java code (later):

```
ldapmodify -H ldap://my.ldap.server:389 -D "myldapadmin" -W -ZZ
Enter LDAP Password:
dn: CN=John Westood,OU=L100,DC=l,DC=woods
changetype: modify
replace: uPwd
uPwd:: 234WF34TG2U
modifying entry "CN=John Westood,OU=L100,DC=l,DC=woods"
```

... as you can see, it asks me for myldapadmin's password, I enter it, and the modification happens.

Here is what I am doing from Java, I want to do the same modification, I am running it on the same server. I have imported the SSigned LDAP SSL certificate into java first.

```
Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://my.ldap.server:389");

// Create initial context
LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);

ctx.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "myldapadmin");
ctx.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "myadminpass");

// Start TLS (STARTTLS is also used by the console command ldapmodify)
StartTlsResponse tls = (StartTlsResponse) ctx.extendedOperation(new 
StartTlsRequest());
SSLSession sess = tls.negotiate();

//Modification of 'uPwd' attribute
ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[1];
Attribute mod0 = new BasicAttribute("uPwd", "4G45G435G436UJWG");
mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, mod0);
ctx.modifyAttributes("CN=John Westood,OU=L100,DC=l,DC=woods", mods);

// Stop TLS
tls.close();
// Context close
ctx.close();
```

I get exception in method ctx.modifyAttributes. The Exception is the following:

```
javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 - 0000052D: SvcErr: DSID-031A12D2, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0
```

Anybody have idea why modify uPwd works with STARTLS from commandline, but not from Java ?

Comment: Why do you think the issue is `STARTLS`? AFAIK you should just get a Connection refused error if that was the problem. It seems like your Java program is **not** performing the operation you think. Does you ldap server log all modifications requested? Try to see what the java code is doing

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am not sure it is up to the STARTTLS.

Comment: Anyway, as long as I understand properly, with REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE I am doing a modification of the attribute uPwd over a STARTTLS layer, that is exactly what the ldapmodify command is doing from the command line. ldapmodify is working, but REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE in Java - not. STARTTLS and Authentication seems to be fine in Java, exception is thrown on routine code for attribute modification.

Comment: According to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290539/ldap-operationnotsupportedexception-error-code-53-0000001f  you may be using the wrong port. Try to use `636` instead of `389`

Comment: Thank you, but we've already tried that. And also, why ldapmodify uses 389 ?

Comment: Did you check the result with the new password to verify that the ldapmodify worked? Did it return a 0 exit code?
If the active directory  requires complexity or enforces history, you need a better password with at least upper/lower/number  throw in a special character for good measure

Answer (score 0):

Appears you are trying to change perhaps a password against Microsoft Active Directory (Even though you show openLDAP)
(I have no idea what uPwd could be.)

Changing Microsoft Active Directory [Passwords has several constraints](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Setting%20and%20Changing%20Microsoft%20Active%20Directory%20Passwords).

Once you are confident you have an acceptable connection to Microsoft Active Directory, We have an [example for Changing Microsoft Active Directory Password with JNDI](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Example%20-%20Active%20Directory%20Change%20Password%20JNDI)

FYI: By default startTLS would use 389.

Comment: It did not help. The LDAP server is Microsoft Active Directory. And I have no control over it. That's why I installed OpenLDAP locally to test. I moved ctx.addToEnvironment(SECURITY_PRINCIPAL and SECURITY_REDENTIALS after the TLS handshake, and that made it work connecting and changing passwords on my local OpenLDAP. However on the MS Active Directory server - the WILL NOT PERFORM Exception persist :(